# given a dataframe of 3 columns, plot the first 2 on 1 axis, and the 3rd on a separate axis below it using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, reshape2

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: "x" "colA" "colB" "colC"

```
df <- data.frame(x, colA, colB, colC)
df2 <- melt(data=df, id.vars="x")
```

currently I am doing the following

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap( ~ variable, ncol=1, scales="free")
```

This plots the 3 series (colA, colB, colC) on 3 seperate axis

I want to plot colA and colB on 1 axis, and have a seperate axis under it containing only colC

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the easier way to do is would be using grid.arrange instead of faceting. `p1 <- ggplot(subset(df2, variable==c(colA,colB))) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=value, color=variable)) ` and `p2 <- ggplot(subset(df2, variable==c(colC)) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=value,color=variable))`. After that `library(gridExtra)` and `grid.arrange(p1,p2)`.

Comment: I am still having some difficulty getting this to work... perhaps it is because I am including the index in the original data frame?            say I was to do df <- data.frame(colA, colB, colC)          How would I melt df2 to be in a useable form to use ur solution?

Comment: I split the data into 2 different data frames and used grid.arrange to stitch them together and it worked, but I would still appreciate a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you include `dput(df)` so that I could post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df2$is.colC <- df2$variable == "colC"
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ is.colC, ncol=1, scales="free")
```

We just add a new variable that highlights whether the row is a "colC" row, and facet on that.

[image]

And the data for reference:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
colA <- runif(10)
colC <- runif(10)
colB <- runif(10)
df <- data.frame(x, colA, colB, colC)
df2 <- melt(data=df, id.vars="x")
```